# Drupal 6 - username admin does not exist after inserting a menu item

Tags: drupal, menu, limit, admin

I am using Drupal 6.19 on a company website with 11 languages.
Up until now, everything worked fine. But somehow I reached some limitation in the menu system.
I can add a new menu item to secondary links or other menus with no problem. However, if I try to add a new menu item to primary links, the following happens:

- I cannot add or edit any nodes, Drupal reports "The username admin does not exist." - but the user admin is there and I can login without problems
- The admin menu lacks certain menu items (e.g. links to translating nodes)

If I delete any items from primary links, the issue resolves, but as soon as I try to add another item, it is there again. I can solve this temporarily by deleting some old menu entries, but I need to get past this issue, as I need to add another two languages in the near future, and they'll have about 60 menu items each.

I already tried to:

- Rebuild permissions
- Increase PHP memory limit from 128MB to 256MB
- Disable some modules I rarely use
- Delete orphan menu entries
- Correct menu items that were flagged external but in fact were internal
- Check that all menu items in the DB appear in the Drupal UI and on the website

None of them worked.

Can you suggest me anything about this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Further info: There were some menu items wich pointed to nodes, but was declared external and didn't have the router_path as node/% I changed all these, set external to 0 and router_path to node/%, the issue emerged. When I set the external back, the issue remained, but when I set router_path back, the issue disappeared. So this has something to do with router_path

Comment: There were some orphan menu items (items with no parent item) in the tree which didn't show up in the Drupal UI. I deleted these and corrected all the above external and node% problems. I thought this will solve the problem, but after adding 3 menu items, the problem still occurs. I am clueless...

Comment: Please don't add stuff like "solved" in your titles, the fact that you accepted an answer is enough to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The issue was with Mysql. Increasing the max packet size solved the problem.

Just added the following to mysql config:

```
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

After this, the issue resolved completely.